# Can a PHP script fill a form behind a login page?

Tags: php, forms, scripting, authentication

How can a PHP script complete a login form to enter the members area (I have a username and password), such that it can send POST data to complete another form only accessible if  logged in?

Comment: This sounds like unscrupulous behavior. Such as trying to capture user's passwords, etc.

Comment: Oh lord, no. I simply need to automate access to an online control panel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do but I suggest checking out webrat if you are attempting to test a site.
http://github.com/brynary/webrat

Hope that helps,
David.